# Trouble making executable jar

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, lwjgl

When I try to make an executable jar in netbeans I get this error

C:\lwjgl\lwjgl-2.8.5\res is a directory or can't be read. Not copying the libraries. Not copying the libraries.The res folder holds files like jpgs and wavs that the program relies on to function. I'm using lwjgl, would that be part of the problem? What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

1. Right click on your project folder and click on **>>>>clean and
   build<<<<**
2. right click on your project folder click on **>>>Properties<<<<**  you
   should see the location of your project folder normally this should
   be in your documents folder under NetbeansProject folder. locate
   your project name folder inside is a folder called **>>>dist<<<** in
   there you should find your project name with a small java  cafe
   image which is your jar file.

Comment: I think I worded my problem in a confusing manner; I've edited it for clarity.